# Checking the value of an hash in a spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a service object with a method which returns a hash with values as a result. I try to test this with rspec, but I have difficulties to check the returned values. Here is the spec:

```
it "calculates holiday balance for approved timesheets" do
  subject = GraphBuilder.new.show_holidays(employee)
  subject[:used].should eq("2.0")
end
```

But this returns an error:

```
 no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

The method returns this hash:

```
 [["type", "days"], ["used", 2.0], ["available", 25.0]]
```

What is the right way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: this is a array not hash

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns an array, not a hash.

Convert this array to a hash like below:

```
Hash[[["type", "days"], ["used", 2.0], ["available", 25.0]]]
# => {"type"=>"days", "used"=>2.0, "available"=>25.0}
```